# Is this a bug in Haskell implementation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

While studying the Haskell implementation of `MaybeT`, I stumbled upon an intriguing issue. Some function executions yield results that differ from my expectations.

I'm unsure whether this is a bug or something else entirely.

Here's a description of the problem:

`liftM`([definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#liftM)) is the `fmap` function under the `Monad` type.
Its type signature is:

```hs
liftM :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

`Just` is a constructor for the Maybe type.

`Just 1` results in `Just(1)`.

`Just Nothing` results in `Just(Nothing)`.

However, when I use `liftM Just` (equivalent to `liftM $ Just`), their type signatures are the same:

```hs
liftM Just :: Monad m => m a1 -> m (Maybe a1)
```

Now, when I execute the following line of code:

```hs
(liftM Just) $ Just(1)
```

The result is:

```hs
Just(Just 1) :: Maybe (Maybe t)  -- this aligns with my expectations.
```

But when I execute this line of code:

```hs
(liftM Just) $ Nothing   -- I expected: Just(Nothing) :: Maybe(Maybe a), 
                         -- but actual result: Nothing :: Maybe a ??  
 
(liftM Just) $ (Left 1)  -- I expected: Left(Just 1), but actual result: Left 1 ??
```

The problem is **the returned type doesn't match the function's type signature. (`liftM Just`)**

I expected the result to be: `Just(Nothing) :: Maybe (Maybe t)`. However, in `GHCi`, the actual result is `Nothing :: Maybe t` — this is what I got.

The two types are different.

```hs
Just(Nothing) :: Maybe (Maybe a)
Nothing :: Maybe a

Left(Just 1) :: Either (Maybe a) (Maybe a)
Left 1 :: Either
```

I feel that `Just(Nothing)` and `Nothing` represent distinct values, right?

They shouldn't be conflated, should they?

So, Wouldn't it be more appropriate for `liftM Just $ Nothing` to return `Just(Nothing) :: Maybe (Maybe t)`?

If I want to get a `Just(Nothing)` as a result, What Can I do?

Is this a bug for Haskell, or is there some other reason behind this discrepancy?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `:t (liftM Just) $ Nothing` in GHCi and it'll give you a proper type `Maybe (Maybe a1)` which aligns `m (Maybe a1)`. The same goes for `:t (liftM Just) $ (Left 1)`. It will give you `Num a => Either a (Maybe a1)` which again aligns `m (Maybe a1)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But `Just(Nothing)` Its type is also `Maybe(Maybe a1)`，My question is Why `(liftM Just) $ Nothing` dont  return `Just(Nothing)` as a result  instead of `Nothing`?

Comment: @qwq_890 Consider the type `Maybe (Maybe Bool)`. Can you list all the possible values which have that type? I think this will help you understand part of what's happening here.

Comment: You expect `liftM Just Nothing` to give `Just Nothing`. Fine. But what do you expect `liftM not Nothing` to give? Once you have said what you expect, can you explain how those two expectations are connected? A similar question series applies to `liftM Just (Left 1)` vs. `liftM not (Left 1)`. (Think of this as printf-debugging for the algorithm running in your brain -- with a bit more introspection, we have a better chance of explaining things for you.)

Answer (score 3):

First: this does not have anything to do with `liftM` in particular. For any well-behaving monad (which includes `Maybe`) this is indeed equivalent to `fmap`, which is what you should always use instead.

Let's introduce a type equivalent to `Maybe` but differently named, this will make it clearer what's going on.

```
data Maybe' a = Nothing' | Just' a
 deriving (Show, Functor)     -- requires {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-} on top of your source file
```

Now, what you wrote first is equivalent to

```
> fmap Just $ Just' 1
Just' (Just 1) :: Maybe' (Maybe Integer)
```

First to emphasize that there is no interaction between the `Maybe` and `Maybe'` monads. (In fact we haven't even made `Maybe'` a monad!) You're simply mapping some function over the `Maybe'` functor, and that function happens to have type `Integer -> Maybe Integer`.

In the same framework, your second attempt is

```
> fmap Just Nothing'
Nothing' :: Maybe' (Maybe Integer)
```

In this case it doesn't really matter at all that you pass `Just`, because mapping anything over `Nothing'` always gives you back `Nothing'`. It's the same as with the perhaps less confusing

```
> fmap (+1) Nothing'
Nothing' :: Maybe' (Maybe Integer)
```

For the `Either` example it's basically the same story, except that the `Left` constructor contains an additional value that `Nothing'` does not have, but this does not partake in any `Functor` semantics.

Comment: Thanks, I tryied `fmap Just $ Just'(1)`, and got `Just'(Just 1)`. And then, I tried `fmap Just $ Left(1)`, which I expected it should return `Left(Just 1)`. `Just'` is replaced by Left. But the actual result is `Left 1`, and I'm confused about the reason.

Comment: It's because when you `fmap` over an `Either` value, the function (in your case `Just`) is only applied when the it's `Right`. When it's `Left` it is kept intact.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `liftM` uses de `Functor` instance of the second argument. Let me clarify:

```
-- notice you should use fmap, not liftM. 
-- But I'll keep your original concerns

-- for the sake of example, let's do something easier
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne n = n + 1 

-- apply this func to this arg
--       |            |
> liftM addOne $ Just 3 
Just 4

-- apply this func to this arg, but there is no arg
--       |            |
> liftM addOne $ Nothing
Nothing
```

Given the above example, is clear that `liftM f (Just x) == Just (f x)` and `liftM f Nothing == Nothing`. (Actually, this is the exact implementation of `Maybe` functor's instance)

Now I think you get confused when doubling the `Maybe`s. So lets apply the same argument

```
-- first notice that Just is a function!!!
-- in ghci type
> :t Just
Just :: a -> Maybe a

-- so Just is a plain function, in the same meaning addOne
-- is a plain function in the example above, hence

-- apply this func to this arg
--       |            |
> liftM Just  $  Just 4
Just (Just 4)

-- apply this func to this arg, but there is no arg
--       |            |
> liftM Just  $  Nothing
Nothing
```

As you can see, there is nothing special in using `addOne` or `Just` as functions. They behave the same way. Now your problem with `Left` is due to the fact that `Either` type `Functor`'s intance is only for the `Right` constructor. Let me give an example:

```
-- again: use fmap, not liftM. 

addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne n = n + 1 

-- apply this func to this arg
--       |             |
> liftM addOne $ Right 3
Right 4

-- Do not apply addOne. The Either functor is intended behave like this.
> liftM addOne $ Left 1
Left 1 -- !!

-- Apply on the right, do not apply on the left. Why? The reasons are beyond 
-- the scope of this answer, but is related among other things with the
-- usage of either as an error monad, so Left constructor is like Nothing
-- in Maybe

-- The same happens when using Just.

-- apply this func to this arg
--       |             |
> liftM Just  $  Right 3
Right (Just 3)

> liftM Just $ Left 1
Left 1
```